# Always move to specific uiviewcontroller

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios5

I have a IOS app, that uses a network connection, and at times, it looses this network connection, whenever it does, I want the app to move back to a specific UIViewController..  What is the best way to achieve this?

Can I do this from the appDelegate?

Comment: Are you using `UINavigationController` as your top controller?

Comment: no, the "main menu" is just a UIViewController with a bunch of segues to other modal view controllers.

Comment: when you say it "loses this network connection", what kind of connection are you doing and which classes (e.g. `NSURLConnection`, `NSInputStream`, etc.) are you utilizing?

Comment: its a CFReadStreamRef/NSInputStream socket based connection.  Another option, I guess is to handle it per UIViewController, so each one could handle the loss of the connection, if that is a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the [Reachability class described in the Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)? If not, you should take a look at it. It will give you network status, including whether you are connected to the internet. It has a notification of network status change so you can put an observer in you app delegate or anywhere else you need it to accomplish your objective.

There is a lot of help already available on the web with examples on how to use Reachability, and [this one](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-testing-network-reachability/) may be something you can start with.

### Update

Raachability change notifications can be used to inform your app when the connection is lost or restored. See the notification statement in the code below for the Reachability class;

```
static void ReachabilityCallback(SCNetworkReachabilityRef target, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags, void* info)

{

    #pragma unused (target, flags)

    NSCAssert(info != NULL, @"info was NULL in ReachabilityCallback");

    NSCAssert([(NSObject*) info isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]], @"info was wrong class in ReachabilityCallback");



    //We're on the main RunLoop, so an NSAutoreleasePool is not necessary, but is added defensively

    // in case someon uses the Reachablity object in a different thread.

    NSAutoreleasePool* myPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];



    Reachability* noteObject = (Reachability*) info;

    // Post a notification to notify the client that the network reachability changed.

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: noteObject];



    [myPool release];

}
```

For this to work you have to call startNotifier:

```
- (BOOL) startNotifier

{

    BOOL retVal = NO;

    SCNetworkReachabilityContext    context = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};

    if(SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef, ReachabilityCallback, &context))

    {

        if(SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(reachabilityRef, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode))

        {

            retVal = YES;

        }

    }

    return retVal;

}
```

Comment: there is a perfect comment on that site: Reachability the way you are using it is flawed. The Reachability code was not meant to be used the way you are using it... more on that link.